# iverilog testbench module with outputs

Tags: verilog, fpga, iverilog

I'm trying to make a testbench to simulate a working top level module (and child module) however I can't get iverilog to handle the output of top correctly (LEDS,RS232Rx and RS232Tx are physical pins)

here's my attempt at a testbench

```
module test();
initial begin
    $dumpfile("test.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,test);
    # 1024 $stop;
end 
reg clk = 0; always #1 clk = !clk;
//reg rx,tx;
reg [7:0] opl;
top top1 ( .clk(clk), .RS232Rx(rx), .RS232Tx(tx), .LEDS(opl) );
endmodule
```

I'm seeing error like this

```
iverilog -o test-design testbench.v top.v
top.v:47: error: LEDS is not a valid l-value in test.top1.
top.v:8:      : LEDS is declared here as wire.
testbench.v:10: error: reg opl; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
testbench.v:10: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
testbench.v:10:      : Port 4 (LEDS) of top is connected to opl
3 error(s) during elaboration.
```

I've tried alsorts of things but with not much in the way of an illuminating or different error message, the best LEDS as a testbench output, showing only an error in top.v which is working... I see very similar errors with rx,tx but commented them out to make a shorter output...

just to reiterate top.v does, not only synthesize but behaves exactly as expected on actual hardware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that despite my top level design was able to output to a wire, iverilog wasn't happy to do this,

adding

```
reg [7:0] leds;
assign LEDS=leds;
```

allows my top level design to work on hardware (as before), but also iverilog (icarus) now seems able to deal with it...